# Split on separator only and explicitly on that separator

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a slight issue whereby our API is returning a string that needs to be formatted into a list.

Example string:

`"*list1. **subItemOflist. *list2 **subItemOfList2."`

which would need to be formatted to:

```
 - list1
  - subItemOfList
 - list2
  - subItemOfList2
```

I have created a pipe that would split on '*'. However, the sub-items also contains astericks which are split too.

```js
const mockstring = '*list. **sublist.';
const splitList = mockstring.split('*').splice(1);
console.log(splitList);
```

produces

```
[
   "list. ",
   "",
   "sublist."
]
```

note the empty array nodes.

Answer (score 1):

`split` takes a regular expression as a parameter so you can use lookaround assertions in it to only match "*" when it's not preceded or followed by another "*": `mockstring.split(/(?<!\*)\*(?!\*)/)`

If you want to split o an arbitrary amount of "*" (but at least one) then the regular expression is: `mockstring.split(/\*+/)`